# recv() with length zero is valid?

Tags: c, sockets

Using the recv() function in C to read from a 'stream' socket, can the len parameter be zero?

The recv() function returns zero for 'remote connection closed' and the number of bytes actually read on normal operation, so it sounds problematic if it should read zero bytes.

P.S.
Yes I know to deal with it separately, and not get to this situation, still I'm wondering if the function can handle it, I can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: not sure why this is problematic? What would you expect read() to return when you ask it to read 0 bytes? 1? -1?

Comment: @BlackBear, not yet, I'd much rather get answer if somebody knows than to construct a test - dealing with sockets even the simplest test will need to set something to connect to, establish connection and then try to see what happens.

Comment: I've just tried it on Windows on a blocking socket, TCP. `recv(s,b,0,0)`  hangs until there's some incoming data or the connection is closed, then it returns 0. If there's already incoming data, it returns 0 immediately. `WSAGetLastError()` and `errno` return 0 after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is "it depends". **If it is not specified by the standard** (and indeed I believe it isn't) any implementation could do as it pleases.

- It could fail with `EINVAL`
- It could hang
- It could return `0` and go on
- It could print a funny message and start the game rogue (I understand `gcc` used to do that :)) )

Actually on my implementation, it returns 0 and goes on. To check if it failed or simply returned 0, you can check `errno` after the call, so it's not as problematic as you may think.

Comment: The documentation on my system (Linux) clearly defines how `recv` behaves, and there nothing about a buffer length of zero that prevents any of that behaviour. I don't see why you think zero is somehow exceptional, and somehow exceptional enough that the defined behaviour should be ignored, so I think your answer is wrong. See my answer for details.

Comment: As I said, I felt it might be a problem due to the return value, and generally because it's strange. I didn't know and wasn't sure which is why I asked.

Comment: Returning zero normally means that the socket has been closed. So, when the given length is zero, there is nothing meaningful that recv() can return, except EINVAL maybe. So, never call recv() with length = 0.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `recv` on my system (Linux) says

> If no messages are available at the socket, the receive calls wait for a message to arrive

and

> If a message is too long to fit in the supplied buffer, excess bytes may be discarded depending on the type of socket the message is received from.

Based on the documentation, I would expect my `recv` to wait for a message, then effectively discard it (UDP) or leave it in the stream (TCP).

This could be used to test if a non-blocking TCP socket has data waiting.

**Update**: Testing reveals that this interpretation of the documentation is accurate.

Server:

```
$ perl -MIO::Socket::INET -E'
   my $s = IO::Socket::INET->new(Listen => 1) or die $!;
   say $s->sockport;

   my $c = $s->accept or die $!;
   say "[".localtime."] connected";

   $c->recv(my $buf, 0) // die $!;
   say "[".localtime."] received";

   say <$c>;
'
39493
[Fri May 13 13:49:53 2011] connected
[Fri May 13 13:49:55 2011] received
foo
```

Client:

```
$ perl -MIO::Socket::INET -E'
   my $s = IO::Socket::INET->new(
      PeerAddr => "127.0.0.1",
      PeerPort => $ARGV[0],
   ) or die $!;
   sleep 2;
   say $s "foo";
' 39493
```

(These Perl functions are just thin interfaces to the system calls. Feel free to rewrite them in C.)

Comment: While this works, could it be that perl behaves this way but implementation of C wouldn't? could it be that this "thin interface" also wraps it with some kind of edge-cases handling. I appreciate your answer, but still feels an explained "it depends" is the more accurate answer. when (and if at all) I'll finally test it for myself I might update here.

Comment: @Xenorose, I went by the *system* documentation (`man recv`), not Perl's. You are more than welcome to reimplement the test in C. If you email it to me (ikegami@adaelis.com), I'll even replace the Perl code in my answer with it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's undefined ... looking at Linux it's passed all the way down to the "driver" (ie. tcp, etc.) so it can mean something, but again I don't think that meaning is defined well. Certainly SuS doesn't say anything explicit about it.

I think you are almost certainly better off just not doing it, and using MSG_PEEK with 1 byte or poll() depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

POSIX's page about `recv()` is not really clear about it. In a non-normative part ("Application Usage"), it says `recv()` on a socket is equivalent to `read()` if no flags are given. POSIX's page about `read()` says a read of 0 bytes may check for errors; if there is no error or the implementation does not check, nothing happens and 0 is returned.

Answer (score -4):

I don't think the length parameter can be zero since even an empty string (message) needs to be terminated with '\0'.

Comment: A "message" from a socket is not necessarily a nul-terminated string.

Comment: ... and it is not necessarily a string at all :-D

Comment: OK, my bad. Note taken. Still I think the concept of a zero byte buffer, although allowed in C, is questionable.